# Can't boot any OS after windows update

Tags: ubuntu, boot, memory, grub

One fine day I hit windows update and restart  and I left it to update, but Ubuntu was up in boot priority.
I later came to check on the status of update and now I can't boot into any OS.
It doesn't matter which OS I choose, CPU will shutdown after 2-3 seconds while trying to boot. I tried booting with live USB but the same thing happens, as soon as I choose Ubuntu from the live USB stick grub menu, it shuts itself down and restarts, and the loop continues.
CMOS battery seems to be working fine, as the time in BIOS looks good. The PC doesn't turn off until I hit the OS to boot, so I guess Power Supply is also Okay.
Is it possible that there's some problem with RAM. I checked with no RAM, GRUB didn't load and that was expected, but is it possible that even though grub loads, the RAM maybe faulty?

Comment: Get the computer manufacturer's Hardware Test App and test all hardware. That is a good starting point here.

Comment: Check BIOS to be sure that Fast Boot is off, because that forces the system to try booting from a file in SSD or HDD. Also, test that Live USB drive on another PC -- sometimes, there is an error in making it. If defective, just use Rufus to rebuild it.

Comment: If you have another computer for preparing a boot media, try running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/).

Comment: Hi @John, it's a dell optiplex CPU, not sure how to perform hardware checks but will look into it.

Comment: Dell Support site has Hardware Test Apps for it various models.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes fast boot and secure boot is off, and just to be sure that wasn't happening, I disconnected my HDD from the mb and tried to boot solely with live usb, but I'll try reusing rufus to flash ubuntu iso

Comment: ok thanks @John, will check it out now

Comment: @John ok there's this support assist program, but it doesn't return any error and completes the check smoothly

Comment: If hardware is OK and Fast Boot is OFF, check why Secure Boot is OFF and then otherwise something has damaged the GRUB setup or some other issue.